# Solr - Getting facet counts without returning search results

Tags: solr, faceted-search

I need to return only the facet counts from solr. So I basically want to search over all documents and return the facet counts, but I don't want to return any search results. Is this possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 58, accepted):

Setting `facet=true` will enable faceting and setting `rows=0` will prevent any results being returned. Conveniently the `numFound` will show you how many results were found.

Answer (score 10):

I guess the obvious solution would be to search using a wildcard and specify that you want zero results returned.

That's my solution so far.

Comment: Returning zero results along with a wildcard on the id field is going to be the easiest.

Comment: There's nothing in the question to suggest that wildcard is the correct query; or that any particular field should be constrained to any specific value or set of values.

Answer (score 0):

So, from what I have understood if I need to get facets count for all documents in a paginated system, I need to make two requests (selects):
- The first to get the facets count for all documents.
- And the second to get the documents from current page.