# SolrNet : Keep Facet count when filtering query

Tags: solr, solrnet

I receive the following facets when I query *:*

```
"Field1": [
  {
    "Key": "Best Facet 1",
    "Value": 999
  },
  {
    "Key": "Best Facet 2",
    "Value": 999
  }
],
"Field2": [
  {
    "Key": "Second Best Facet 1",
    "Value": 421
  },
  {
    "Key": "Second Best Facet 2",
    "Value": 103
  }
]
```

Now I want to apply filter query (fq) on Field2 = "Second Best Facet 2"

The results I receive are

```
"Field1": [
  {
    "Key": "Best Facet 1",
    "Value": 103
  },
  {
    "Key": "Best Facet 2",
    "Value": 103
  }
],
"Field2": [
  {
    "Key": "Second Best Facet 1",
    "Value": 103
  },
  {
    "Key": "Second Best Facet 2",
    "Value": 103
  }
]
```

I need the facet counts to remain consistent and not be affected by the filter applied. I can't find any solutions to the problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can [tag your filters and tell Solr to ignore those filters](https://wiki.apache.org/solr/SimpleFacetParameters#Tagging_and_excluding_Filters) when calculating the facet scores:

```
fq={!tag=dt}doctype:pdf&facet.field={!ex=dt}doctype
```

`fq=` applies the filter, but tags the filter with the tag `dt`, and by telling `facet.field` to exclude any filter tagged as `dt`, it will still calculate counts across the whole collection and not just the filtered values.

> Filter exclusion is supported for all types of facets. Both the tag and ex local params may specify multiple values by separating them with commas.