# Error from server at https://localhost:8983/solr: Invalid Number: [0 TO 9.99]

Tags: solr, sap-commerce-cloud

When we are hitting the range query from hybris server we are getting Error

**org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpSolrClient$RemoteSolrException: Error from server at https://localhost:8983/solr: Invalid Number: [0 TO 9.99]**

Where as if we are passing the value from solr admin console it's working as expected.

[image]

From hybris we are passing query like **:relevance:length:[0 TO 9.99]**

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you please put a debug point in the method DefaultFacetSearchStrategy#search and copy the actual query that is created by hybris? (it is an instance of SolrQuery class)  Also, you can just enable debug for that class.

Comment: Yeah i have done that. in query i can see fq=allCategories_string_mv:Test&fq=(catalogId:"TestProductCatalog"+AND+catalogVersion:"Online")&fq={!tag%3Dfk3}length_double:\[0\+TO\+9.99\]. But getting invalid number from RemoteSolrException Error from server at https://localhost:8983/solr: Invalid Number: [0 TO 9.99]

Comment: As you can see from the query fq={!tag%3Dfk3}length_double:[0\+TO\+9.99] your part goes to an "FQ" param, but when you execute it from SOLR Console you put it into "Q" param. Check this out :
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20988516/difference-between-q-and-fq-in-solr

Comment: But i am passing :relevance:length:[0 TO 9.99] as search query(i.e 'q' param) to the controller. Internally it is adding to fq. Also can you please guide me how to get the range filter without defining the range set in index property. Thanks

Comment: I have fixed the issue by overriding convertQueryField() of AbstractFacetSearchQueryPopulator to avoid escape characters.