# Query to omit rows with empty records

Tags: solr

How do you omit rows with empty records in Solr?  I've tried a few permutations but nothing seems to be working:

1: "John", "blue", "dog"
2: "Sue", "brown", "zebra"
3: "Mike", "red", ""  <--do not return this row with the results
4: "Jen", "green", "cat"

Comment: These do not look like Solr docs. Are you talking abt multi-valued fields? What do you mean by "rows"?

Comment: Sorry, I come to this more from SQL.  No, those are not actual Solr docs, just a pseudo-code example of related record sets.  I want 1, 2, and 4 but not 3 because the 3rd value in 3 has nothing in it.

Comment: Why did 3 match your query then? I am not sure what your query is and what type the field is indexed as

Comment: 3 shouldn't match my query because it has an empty field.  Only 1, 2, and 4 should match my query.  This is not an actual example.  I don't know what the query is to return only 1, 2, and 4 but not 3, which is my question.

Comment: Here is a more specific example:
 <doc>
    <arr name="productname">
      <str>ABC</str>
    </arr>
    <str name="id">12345</str>
    <str name="enu">Open </str>
    <str name="deu">Öffnen</str>
    <str name="esp">Abra</str>
    <str name="fra">Ouvrez</str>
    <str name="ita">Aprire</str>
   <doc>
    <arr name="productname">
      <str>DEF</str>
    </arr>
    <str name="id">23456</str>
    <str name="enu">OpenGL</str>
    <str name="fra">OpenGL</str>
    <str name="plk">OpenGL</str>
</doc>

Comment: The first doc contains a string named "esp," the second one doesn't.  So if fq = enu:open (as it does in both docs) how do I omit the second doc which does not have an esp field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`esp:[* TO *]` restricts to documents which contain `esp` field, so your query could be like:

```
q=esp:[* TO *]&fq=enu:open
```

Comment: Close...turns out to be q:*:*&fq:[enu:open, esp:[* TO *]] or something more like that.  If you edit to reflect this I'm more than glad to award points!

Comment: Well, yes, you can add it as another filter query, but only if you want to cache the results in filter cache. You should understand the difference between `q` and `fq` before using `fq` for all the conditions. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/14866752/1333610

Comment: Thanks for pointing me to that post.  I get the difference between f and fq not but then I don't understand.  Wouldn't it be the other way around?  q=enu:open&fq=esp:[* TO *] or "Search all records where enu contains open and then filter out the ones that don't contain esp?"

Comment: Never mind, just answered my own stupid question.  Thanks Arun!